# Use same fields for type and input in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

In one of my projects that uses GraphQL, I define a `type` and an `input` with the same fields.

ex.

```
type SomeType {
    name: String
    id: String
}

input SomeInput {
    name: String
    id: String
}
```

This seems redundant since I have to define the same fields twice.  Is it possible, to define a set of fields, and have both `SomeType` and `SomeInput` contain those fields?  This would work similar to inheritance in object oriented programming, where you would have some base, and ideally each of these would inherit from it.

for example, it might look like:

```
SomeBase {
    name: String
    id: String
}

type SomeType extends SomeBase {}

input SomeInput extends SomeBase {}
```

Is this possible?  If so, how would you achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether `graphql` supports inheritance, but there are interfaces. In your example:

```
interface IUser {
  name: String!
  id: String!
} 

type User implements IUser {
  name: String
  id: String
}

type UserInput implements IUser {
  name: String
  id: String
}
```

This will certainly not reduce the boilerplate, but will at least ensure that you can maintain a common contract for the types.

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestion, but the goal is to reduce the boilerplate.  So interfaces are not the answer unfortunately.